# How to fit iframe content according to a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have to embedd an iframe to an external website. I don't have any control on the external website. I have to put my website inside this iframe where I can only tell the size of the iframe.
However I would like that the content inside the iframe adapts to the mobile device.

I have already done this:
  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

I can't wrap the iframe with a div. Because I don't have access to the external website. I was only given the iframe, in which I can set the dimension and that's it.
So I would like to know, how can I solve this issue? How to adapt the content present inside of an iframe, to a mobile device?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to set its width as 100%.

It should work both to desktop & mobile screens.

Comment: I have to specify height and width. Only with width, is not doable. Have this limitation unfortunately.

Comment: <iframe src="....." frameborder="0" width="100%" height="950"></iframe>

Specify height. Height won't cause any issues on responsiveness.

Comment: even setting width and height as you suggested the webpage is all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

This may be able to help you. I had a similar problem and this was the solution.

```
 <iframe Class="Edit1" id="Edit1" width="342" height="223" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/????????" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>Video Loading...</iframe> 

 <script>
 window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);

  function myFunction() {
    var $myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        $myWidth=($myWidth * (4 / 4));
     var $myHeight= ($myWidth / (16/9));    // var myHeight="900.876976978";
        $myHeight= Math.round($myHeight);
    
    document.getElementById("Edit1").width = $myWidth -40;
    document.getElementById("Edit1").height = $myHeight;
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I can't add any classes to the iframe.  Also that script, where should i put it? I don't access to the external website.

Comment: You don't need to have the class part. Regarding those settings, in the iframe you can make changes to what you want.  You will note that only the id="Edit1" is used by myfunction().

Comment: This above code snippet code is used on a web page http://www.iwalks.ie and the exact same page runs inside the mobile app for iwalks.ie .. This video shows the same page with the nicely positioned iframe in a mobile app:  https://youtu.be/FgNmr9htaqs    So in this case you can see it working in a regular web page and inside a mobile app.

Comment: I can't even set an id on the iframe. :/